# How can I log all outgoing email in Django?

Tags: python, django, logging, python-logging, django-email

My Django application sends out quite a bit of emails and I've tried testing it thoroughly. However, for the first few months, I'd like to log all outgoing emails to ensure that everything is working smoothly.

Is there a Django module that allows me to do this and makes the outgoing emails visible through the administration panel?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wrote a custom email backend which logs the stuff to a model.

Here's my backend:

```
from django.core.mail.backends.smtp import *
from django.db import transaction

from modules.common.models import *

class LoggingEmailBackend(EmailBackend):
    """
    A wrapper around the SMTP backend that logs all emails to the DB.
    """
    def send_messages(self, email_messages):
    """
    A helper method that does the actual logging
    """
    with transaction.commit_on_success():

        for email_message in email_messages:

            email_record = Email.objects.create(
                to='; '.join(email_message.recipients()),
                subject=email_message.subject, body=email_message.body,
            )

            try:
                return super(LoggingEmailBackend, self)._send(
                    email_message
                )
            except:
                email_record.ok = False
                return False
            finally:
                email_record.ok = True
                return True
```

Here's the model:

```
class Email(models.Model):
    """
    Model to store all the outgoing emails.
    """
    when = models.DateTimeField(
        null=False, auto_now_add=True
    )
    to = models.EmailField(
        null=False, blank=False,
    )
    subject = models.CharField(
         null=False, max_length=128,
    )
    body = models.TextField(
        null=False, max_length=1024,
    )
    ok = models.BooleanField(
        null=False, default=True,
    )
```

Here's my model:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from modules.common.models import *

class EmailAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
    Admin part for managing the the Email model
    """
    list_display = ['to', 'subject', 'ok',]
    list_filter = ['ok']
    readonly_fields = ['when', 'to', 'subject', 'body', 'ok']
    search_fields = ['subject', 'body', 'to']

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False


admin.site.register(Email, EmailAdmin)
```

Comment: This will not record ok = False on failure. The model is not saved.

Answer (score 10):

Since the OP asked about logging and not about saving to DB, here's a middleware that does that:

```
import django.core.mail.backends.smtp
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)  # or you could enter a specific logger name

class LoggingBackend(django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend):

  def send_messages(self, email_messages):
    try:
        for msg in email_messages:
            logger.info(u"Sending message '%s' to recipients: %s", msg.subject, msg.to)
    except:
        logger.exception("Problem logging recipients, ignoring")

    return super(LoggingBackend, self).send_messages(email_messages)
```

and then in your settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'whereiputit.LoggingBackend'
```

Comment: Hey do you have an idea if this would not work in celery? It seems to have trouble to be imported for me

Comment: @Snake_py in principle, no reason it shouldn't work in celery.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if there exists a module that works this way, but writing a custom one is a piece of cake. Just create a separate model and every time you send an email, create a new instance ( use a custom method for email sending ). Then, link this model with the admin and bingo..

Answer (score 2):

Django offers custom E-Mail backends, [you can write one on your own](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#defining-a-custom-email-backend).